# eCharts: Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: typescript, svelte, echarts

I am trying to used eCharts in a Svelte app. I use typescript and I installed eCharts types.

I have:

> "@types/echarts": "^4.9.15" and
> "echarts": "^5.3.3",

It fails at myChart.setOption<echarts.EChartsOption>(...)

```
<script lang="ts">
    import * as echarts from 'echarts';

    type EChartsOption = echarts.EChartsOption;

    let chartDom = document.getElementById('main')!;
    let myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);
    let option: EChartsOption;

    option = {};

    myChart.on('updateAxisPointer', function (event: any) {
        const xAxisInfo = event.axesInfo[0];
        if (xAxisInfo) {
            const dimension = xAxisInfo.value + 1;
            myChart.setOption<echarts.EChartsOption>({
                series: {
                    id: 'pie',
                    label: {
                        formatter: '{b}: {@[' + dimension + ']} ({d}%)'
                    },
                    encode: {
                        value: dimension,
                        tooltip: dimension
                    }
              }
         });
      }
  });

  myChart.setOption<echarts.EChartsOption>(option);
```

Comment: Remove the @types/echarts dependency as its outdated.  For ECharts 5 it'll use the types defined in the main ECharts package.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the dependency. So, you are saying that it will .. but not now?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: @DaveMeehan Sorry, I just realized that I can already use the types with eCharts 5. Thank you